# Android file transfer difficulties

Tags: nautilus, android, music, samsung, transfer

I'm having problems transferring stuff to my Samsung Galaxy S4 and its memory card.

The long and short of it is that I just can't transfer certain files across: the music is mostly in .wma format, but several songs just won't transfer and the transfer protocol grinds to a halt every time it encounters one it doesn't like, citing various errors, such as "could not send object" and "could not get object handles" furthermore, clicking on the mounted drive simply seems to render the GUI unresponsive and the progress bar says I'm going at a speed of less than 100 kilobytes per second, file transfer via Samsung Kies Air is woeful as well, as it tells me that I have to install java to run it, whereupon I just run into the tons-of-tar.gz-files-but-no-executable problem.

At the moment I'm trying to transfer to the card via nautilus, I am seemingly unable to sync with rythmbox and Banshee can't seem to find any of my music at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

okay, I can officially close this one off now.

It turns out that Android's MTP was at fault- when transferring files to and from a USB stick, transfer was fine, transferring between the phone and the computer was not, meaning the Android was the problem.

Since putting it in, I tried running the phone in PTP transfer mode, rather than MTP transfer and, as if by magic, my issues are gone.

To access this option, simply plug the S4 into the computer and you should get a little icon appear, telling you that it is connected as a media device, simply pull the menu down, tap the icon and change to PTP mode.

[image: options screenshot]

if at first you don't succeed and all that jazz.

Comment: This worked for me with Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini + Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Relief! :)