# MTP error while transfering files

Tags: mtp, ptp

After connecting my android via usb cord when i try to transfer files from my computer to my phone it brings error can't write to this location.

This is the screenshot of the error message i get

[image]

After trying the solution suggested by ElderGreek I still get another error whose screenshot is below

[image]

Here is the result for `lsb_release -a`

`No LSB modules are available. Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS Release:    18.04 Codename:   bionic`

```
Linux rasheed-Lenovo-V130-15IGM 5.4.0-67-generic #75~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 23 19:17:50 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is the result of `uname -a`

```
Linux rasheed-Lenovo-V130-15IGM 5.4.0-67-generic #75~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 23 19:17:50 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/684128/167115) to fix the error but if you have problems with slow transfer, refer to [this related answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299512/accessing-data-on-a-mounted-phone-takes-forever) which suggests using ADB instead of MTP because it's faster. Another thing to consider would be to upload the files to google drive so you don't have to use a USB cable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting MTP enabled devices to work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/a/684128/167115). If not, please let us know and explain why. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @mchid but the method doesnt work, but i've updated the question with a screenshot of the error message

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android file transfer difficulties](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307069/android-file-transfer-difficulties)

Comment: @ElderGeek i tried the method there using ptp it also brings an error

Comment: The screenshot of the error has been updated in the question

Comment: @Rasheed thank you for that update. In order to bring some context into your problem , please [edit] the output of `lsb_release -a` into your question. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek I've done that

Comment: @Rasheed Thank you for helping us help you. I've updated the tags accordingly. I've successfully transferred files using PTP from Android to Ubuntu 18.04 on numerous occasions. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/308269/225694) worked for me and others. I used nautilus to do the actual copying. There may be a bug in gphoto that you are running into. Please [edit] the output of `uname -a` into your post.

Comment: @ElderGeek I've updated the post with the `uname -a` result

Comment: @Rasheed Please [edit] your question to include which answers you tried from the questions suggested by @mchid and myself. Thank you for helping us help you! The output of `lsusb` with the device connected would also be useful. Again, thank you for helping us help you!